# Oracle SQL query to compare data of a row with that of 28 days back

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table **TableA** like below:

```
WEEK |COL1 |COL2 |COL3 |COL4 |COL5 |CLOSING_BALANCE |REPORT_DATE
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|----------------|-----------
----------------------------------------------------------------
WEEK_1|123|Y|1|123|Y|100|19/07/2016
WEEK_5|123|Y|1|123|Y|300|16/08/2016
WEEK_9|123|Y|1|123|Y|400|13/09/2016
WEEK_5|345|N|2|859|N|658|16/08/2016
WEEK_1|456|N|5|795|N|50|19/07/2016
WEEK_13|456|N|5|795|N|230|11/10/2016
WEEK_9|456|N|5|795|N|120|13/09/2016
WEEK_1|567|Y|4|567|N|111|19/07/2016
WEEK_13|567|Y|4|567|N|222|11/10/2016
WEEK_1|678|N|2|564|Y|900|19/07/2016
WEEK_9|789|N|3|458|Y|200|13/09/2016
```

Each row needs to be compared with 28days (report_date-28) back data for the same combination of COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 and COL5.

Let's assume I am comparing week_5 with week_1

*Case1: Present in current row and present 28days back as well.*

Say for week_5 I get a matching combination of COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 and COL5 28 days back i.e in week_1. Now in the output I want 1 single row for these two rows, with week_1 closing_base as prev_closing_base and week_5 closing_base as current_closing base.

Example: week_5/123 week_1/123

*Case2: Present 28days back but missing in current*

If a combination is present in say week_1 but missing in week_5. I want prev_closing_base as week_1's closing_base and current_closing base as 0.
Example: week_1/678

*Case3: Present in current row but missing 28 days back*

If a combination is present in say week_5 but missing in week_1. I want prev_closing_base as 0  and current_closing base as closing_base of week_5.
Example: week5/345 & week_9/789

The output should be as below:-

```
WEEK |  COL1 |  COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5   | CLOSING_BALANCE_28DAYS_AGO | CURR_CLOSING_BALANCE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WEEK_1 |456|N|5|795|N|50 |0
WEEK_5 |123|Y|1|123|Y|100|300
WEEK_5 |345|N|2|859|N|0  |658
WEEK_1 |678|N|2|564|Y|900|0
WEEK_9 |789|N|3|458|Y|0  |200
WEEK_9 |123|Y|1|123|Y|300|400
WEEK_13|456|N|5|795|N|120|230
WEEK_1 |567|Y|4|567|N|111|0
WEEK_13|567|Y|4|567|N|0  |222
```

I tried to do full outer join on the same table. But this is not working . Its giving duplicate rows.

```
        select nvl (curr.WEEK, prev.WEEK) WEEK,
               nvl (curr.COL1, prev.COL1) COL1,
               nvl (curr.COL2, prev.COL2) COL2,
               nvl (curr.COL3, prev.COL3) COL3,   
               nvl (curr.COL4, prev.COL4) COL4,
               nvl (curr.COL5, prev.COL5) COL5,
               nvl (prev.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) PREV_CLOSING_BALANCE_28DAYS_AGO,
               nvl (curr.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) CURR_CLOSING_BALANCE
          from TableA curr
               full outer join TableA prev
                  on curr.report_date - 28 = prev.report_date
                     and curr.COL1 = prev.COL1
                     and curr.COL3 = prev.COL3
                     and curr.COL4 = prev.COL4
                     and curr.COL2 = prev.COL2
                     and curr.COL5 = prev.COL5;
```

Left outer join does not seem to work as well

```
    select nvl (curr.year_week, prev.year_week) year_week,
           nvl (curr.COL1, prev.COL1) COL1,
           nvl (curr.COL2, prev.COL2) COL2,
           nvl (curr.COL3, prev.COL3) COL3,   
           nvl (curr.COL4, prev.COL4) COL4,
           nvl (curr.COL5, prev.COL5) COL5,
           nvl (prev.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) PREV_CLOSING_BALANCE_28DAYS_AGO,
           nvl (curr.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) CURR_CLOSING_BALANCE
      from TableA curr
           left outer join TableA prev
              on curr.edw_report_date - 28 = prev.edw_report_date
                 and curr.COL1 = prev.COL1
                 and curr.COL3 = prev.COL3
                 and curr.COL4 = prev.COL4
                 and curr.COL2 = prev.COL2
                 and curr.COL5 = prev.COL5;
```

Output from left outer join:-

```
YEAR_WEEK|MOB_PROMOTION_KEY|BTM_EMPLOYEE_FLG|SIM_ACTIVATION_STATUS_KEY|BTM_HANDSET_KEY|BTM_ADDON_XSPEED4G_FLG|CLOSING_BASE_28DAYS_AGO|CURR_CLOSING_BASE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WEEK_5|123|Y|1|123|Y|100|300
WEEK_1|123|Y|1|123|Y|0|100
WEEK_1|678|N|2|564|Y|0|900
WEEK_5|345|N|2|859|N|0|658
WEEK_9|789|N|3|458|Y|0|200
```

I found that following a procedural approach like below will give me the desired output. But I was thinking if this could be done using a single query. Need your valuable suggestions on this.

```
    BEGIN
       for i in (select distinct a.report_date curr_date, b.report_date prev_date from TableA a, TableA b where a.report_date-28=b.report_date  order by a.report_date)

        LOOP

         insert into TARGET_TABLE  
          select nvl (curr.WEEK, prev.WEEK) WEEK,
               nvl (curr.COL1, prev.COL1) COL1,
               nvl (curr.COL2, prev.COL2) COL2,
               nvl (curr.COL3, prev.COL3) COL3,   
               nvl (curr.COL4, prev.COL4) COL4,
               nvl (curr.COL5, prev.COL5) COL5,
               nvl (prev.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) CLOSING_BALANCE_28DAYS_AGO,
               nvl (curr.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) CURR_CLOSING_BALANCE
          from TableA curr
               inner join TableA prev
                 on curr.report_date-28= prev.report_date
                  and curr.COL1 = prev.COL1
                     and curr.COL3 = prev.COL3
                     and curr.COL4 = prev.COL4
                     and curr.COL2 = prev.COL2
                     and curr.COL5 = prev.COL5
                     where curr.report_date = i.curr_date
                  and  prev.report_date = i.prev_date;

        commit;             

         insert into TARGET_TABLE  
        select nvl (curr.WEEK, prev.WEEK) WEEK,
               nvl (curr.COL1, prev.COL1) COL1,
               nvl (curr.COL2, prev.COL2) COL2,
               nvl (curr.COL3, prev.COL3) COL3,   
               nvl (curr.COL4, prev.COL4) COL4,
               nvl (curr.COL5, prev.COL5) COL5,
               nvl (prev.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) CLOSING_BALANCE_28DAYS_AGO,
               nvl (curr.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) CURR_CLOSING_BALANCE
          from TableA curr
               left outer join TableA prev
                  on curr.report_date-28= prev.report_date
                  and curr.COL1 = prev.COL1
                     and curr.COL3 = prev.COL3
                     and curr.COL4 = prev.COL4
                     and curr.COL2 = prev.COL2
                     and curr.COL5 = prev.COL5             
               where curr.report_date = i.curr_date  
                  and not exists (select 1 from TARGET_TABLE tmp
                            where tmp.COL1 = curr.COL1
                     and tmp.COL3 = curr.COL3
                     and tmp.COL4 = curr.COL4
                     and tmp.COL2 = curr.COL2
                     and tmp.COL5 = curr.COL5)   ;
        commit;


        insert into TARGET_TABLE  
        select nvl (curr.WEEK, prev.WEEK) WEEK,
               nvl (curr.COL1, prev.COL1) COL1,
               nvl (curr.COL2, prev.COL2) COL2,
               nvl (curr.COL3, prev.COL3) COL3,   
               nvl (curr.COL4, prev.COL4) COL4,
               nvl (curr.COL5, prev.COL5) COL5,
               nvl (prev.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) CLOSING_BALANCE_28DAYS_AGO,
               nvl (curr.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) CURR_CLOSING_BALANCE
          from TableA curr
               right outer join TableA prev
                  on curr.report_date-28= prev.report_date
                  and curr.COL1 = prev.COL1
                     and curr.COL3 = prev.COL3
                     and curr.COL4 = prev.COL4
                     and curr.COL2 = prev.COL2
                     and curr.COL5 = prev.COL5             
               where prev.report_date = i.prev_date  
                  and not exists (select 1 from TARGET_TABLE tmp
                            where tmp.COL1 = prev.COL1
                     and tmp.COL3 = prev.COL3
                     and tmp.COL4 = prev.COL4
                     and tmp.COL2 = prev.COL2
                     and tmp.COL5 = prev.COL5)   ;
        commit;

    end loop;
    end;
    /
```

Comment: Have you tried with `left outer join` instead of `full outer join`?

Comment: @Vercelli : Yes, tried that as well. But left outer join is not giving the desired result as well.

Comment: Using a left outer join gets 5 rows instead of 9. Why does your expected result only have four rows - why isn't `week_1/123` included?

Comment: Will there always be a record 28 days back?  a LEFT OUTER SELF JOIN should (99% confident) be what you want so if you are not getting your results that you desire with that perhaps you can post your attempt at the left join and we can help you discover potential issues with how you are joining.  Remember when using a LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL outer join not to use the outer table in your where clause or it because an inner join unless you just test for null

Comment: @Matt: I have tried left outer join. Edited my post and added the left outer join query.

Comment: what does "doesn't seem to work" mean?  That is very vague. All of your NVL() on Col1/2/3 etc can be removed as if they are part of the join they will never be NULL.  Next your procedure just does exactly what your full outer join statement does.  It doen't make since to me get the right side of the equation  Your query for your left join looks like it is written fine so the problem is either in your original query that you have simplified for us or your data in the table doesn't match your expectations.  can you post your actual query that is giving you problems? Or Expected results?

Comment: Why do you NOT want the extra row from the left join? You said EACH ROW from the input....  The sample input has five rows, so the output should also have five rows. The left join does. Your claimed "output" only has four rows, why? Did you also mean, for each group (combination) you only want THE MOST RECENT row compared to whatever the balance was 28 weeks earlier? You didn't say that in your question.... if that is not the case, then what? Why does the output have fewer rows than the input?

Comment: Your logic isn't really clear. Is there no row for WEEK_1/123 because the later row for that key WEEK_5/123 takes precedence; so you want the latest row for a key, with the data from 28 days before? I can almost make this work, but why is the WEEK_1 value you do have 900,0 instead of 0,900 - there is no previous row for that key?

Comment: Thanks all for your quick responses. Sorry for not being able to state my requirement clearly. I have edited my post and have tried to clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

OK then, this gives the desired result on given data:

```
SELECT nvl (curr.week, prev.week) year_week,
    nvl (curr.COL1, prev.COL1) COL1,
    nvl (curr.COL2, prev.COL2) COL2,
    nvl (curr.COL3, prev.COL3) COL3,   
    nvl (curr.COL4, prev.COL4) COL4,
    nvl (curr.COL5, prev.COL5) COL5,
    nvl (prev.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) PREV_CLOSING_BALANCE_28DAYS_AGO,
    nvl (curr.CLOSING_BALANCE, 0) CURR_CLOSING_BALANCE
FROM TableA curr
FULL OUTER JOIN TableA prev
    ON curr.REPORT_DATE - 28 = prev.report_date
    AND curr.COL1 = prev.COL1
    AND curr.COL3 = prev.COL3
    AND curr.COL4 = prev.COL4
    AND curr.COL2 = prev.COL2
    AND curr.COL5 = prev.COL5
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.week prev_week, b.week curr_week, a.report_date prev_date, b.report_date curr_date 
    FROM TableA a
    JOIN TableA b ON a.report_date+28=b.report_date
    ORDER BY a.report_date
) AS dates
    ON (curr.week = dates.curr_week AND curr.REPORT_DATE = dates.curr_date)
        OR (prev.week = dates.prev_week AND prev.REPORT_DATE = dates.prev_date AND curr.REPORT_DATE IS NULL)
WHERE curr.report_date IS NOT NULL OR NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT a.week 
    FROM TableA a 
    JOIN TableA b ON a.report_date+28=b.report_date 
    WHERE b.week = prev.week AND b.report_date = prev.report_date
)
ORDER BY curr.col1;
```

But the code is pretty complex, so please run some tests on a larger dataset.

Comment: Left join is not giving me the required result.

Comment: What result do you get? I tested against the data you provided and it worked for me.

Comment: I don't want this row in the output WEEK_1|123|Y|1|123|Y|0|100. Since a match is found for week_5/123 & week_1/123, I need a single row for them with week_5/123, in that I want prev_closing_base to be populated from week_1 's closing_base and current_closing base populated from week_5 's closing_base
Also for week_1/678... case where it's present 28 days back but missing in current. Left join gives :
WEEK_1 | 678 | N | 2 | 564 | Y | 0 | 900
But I want:
WEEK_1 | 678 | N | 2 | 564 | Y | 900 | 0

Comment: Ok, I see where you are going. I just have one question - how do you decide if WEEK_5 | 345 should appear in CURR or PREV? It's not the oldest nor the newest week and it has no older nor later values.

Comment: While checking for week_5 if we go 28days back, we get week_1. So rows from week_5 becomes my CURR and corresponding rows (for which the combination matches) from week_1 becomes my PREV. Now for week_5/345 we do not get a combination match in week_1, so for this row current_closing_base comes from week_5/345 and prev_closing_base becomes 0

Comment: The query was giving the desired result for the data set I had provided. But it failed when I extended the data set. I have edited and added the data set and the output required